# Programmatically remove tapped APNS from notification bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am stuck in to remove tapped push notification from notification bar.

I already tried using this code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; 
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

This will remove all notification from notification bar can any one help me for the same.

I am searching from last two days but found no solution.

Comment: you want to remove just the specific notification and keep the rest?

Comment: yes Fahim stuck last 2 days do you have any solution please reply me

Comment: check my answer... it has some work... its Apple issue and we have to use another way to solve it..

Comment: can u give me a link for the same..

Comment: no, I don't have link. For this you need to learn SQLLite & local push notification...

Comment: how come Gaurav answer helped you? I just want to know.. he  posted same code that you posted...

Comment: No gaurav answer not helped me.

Comment: then how did you accepted...

Answer (score 0):

*I believe you just want to remove the tapped push from the push list & not all notification.*

***By default Apple has made this. When you click on one push notification, it removes all notification.*** *In code what you are doing is just setting the application badge number, which has nothing to do with push notification.*

I believe what you want is remove just tapped push and keep the rest push as it is. Right?

Well, this can be done, but it have lot of work.

1. When push comes, save the data locally.
2. When you click on push, remove that push from local data.
3. When you close the app, send local push using your local data.

Note: To maintain the badge number, you need to keep update on push that are read.

Comment: this is how SO works... I cannot give you all code and direct answers. What my answer is kind of points that will help... You have to implement those...